# Receive parameters from an URL

Tags: url, arduino

I'm getting URL input from the server as follows:

```
http://10.0.0.70/distance=150/angle=60
```

Now how can I get the distance and angle parameters from this URL and store it into a another variable?

I have to use this in the Arduino programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
char str[] = "http://10.0.0.70/distance=150/angle=60";
char * pch;
char *ptr;
long ret;

pch = strchr(str,'='); // find '='
ret = strtoul(pch, &ptr, 10); // take the number after it (here ret = 150)

pch = strchr(pch+1,'='); // find the next '='
ret = strtoul(pch, &ptr, 10); // take the number after it (here ret = 60)
```